# Qt QRC File path to image file not working

Tags: c++, qt

I was developing on mac and i had no problems with path to QRC, after switching to windows, links to image stopped working. But however qss files can  be referenced and are working!

1) I've created a new Ressource File from Scratch

2) I've Rebuild the Project

3) I've used the path delivered by qt:

[image]

4) Full Path is working:

```
QVariant(QIcon(QPixmap("V:/070_RnD/AssetBrowser_02/images/checkbox.png")));
```

5) QRC-Path isn't

```
QVariant(QIcon(QPixmap(":/myresources/images/checkbox.png")));
```

What can i test more? Ass i said, when i copy the ressource path from default.qss it is recognized, but images not.

QRC-Code:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/myresources">
        <file>images/scrollHandle.png</file>
        <file>images/upArrow.png</file>
        <file>images/downArrow.png</file>
        <file>images/folder-icon.png</file>
        <file>images/branch-closed.png</file>
        <file>images/branch-open.png</file>
        <file>images/checkbox.png</file>
        <file>qss/default.qss</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the qrc file? I suspect the alias may be wrong.

Comment: get rid of the / in /myresources in your qrc. You do not have myresources in the root folder of your filesystem.

Comment: Check whether your qrc file gets rcc'ed and relevent _qrc.cpp file is generated. Check in .pro file whether qrc file is included in that

Comment: @drescherjm i tried it out, but no luck

Comment: @LahiruChandima 1) qrc file is included in pro file 2) rcc is not created, where should it be?

Comment: rcc is Qt resource compiler. It should process resource files specified in the .pro file and generate corresponding cpp files. Check whether qrc_Style.cpp is there in the generated files directory.

Comment: @LahiruChandima qrc_assetBrowser.cpp is in the directory where the *.exe is generated

Comment: Since your resource file name is Style.qrc, generated cpp file name should be qrc_Style.cpp so may be rcc might have missed Style.qrc. Try `Build->Run QMake` and then `Build->Rebuild project`

Comment: @LahiruChandima great! runnig qmake did the trick, now the "qrc_Style.cpp" file is in the generated files folder. Can you wrap it up and write this as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource paths you have used looks compatible with your qrc file. So may be Qt resource compiler may have missed your qrc file.

Check whether your qrc file is included in the .pro file like below.

```
RESOURCES += \
    Style.qrc
```

If it is correctly included in the .pro file, then try `Build->Run QMake` and then `Build->Rebuild project`. This will re-generate the makefile and rebuild the project.